# Find the name of the file or files with a certain text. This command can search through the directory and all sub directories to find all matches

Tags: grep

Trying to find the name of a file by searching for a word that's in the file.

I have tried to look at many examples online but unfortunately I couldn't find a code that outputs the names of the files with that certain word in it.

```
grep -r 'Facebook' *
```

I expected the output to be many names of the files which has the word facebook in it but instead I got output of lines with the word facebook in it which is not what I wanted.

Comment: Should `Facebook` be `in the name of the file` or `inside the file`?

Answer (score 1):

There are many possible solutions in a Unix/Linux environment:

- `find` /path/to/base `-name Facebook`
- `ls -R` /path/to/base `| grep -i "[Ff]acebook"`

etc.

Or there are programmatic approaches written in a language of your choice.  Add more details about what you are trying to do for a better answer.

Comment: If this is what the op wants, `*[Ff]acebook*` would make a better pattern.

Comment: @sjsam:  good point.  I was lazy (originally) since the OP didn't provide a clear indication.

Comment: The question doesn't clearly set the expected output. I have asked for a clarification [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56261565/find-the-name-of-the-file-or-files-with-a-certain-text-this-command-can-search/56261836?noredirect=1#comment99140268_56261565). But, reading between the lines, I hope this is what the op wants.

Answer (score 0):

it should be something like this

```
grep -l "Facebook" *
```

this is going to search for all the files and not sub directories in the current folder and produce the name of the file where a match was found

from man page of grep:

-L, --files-without-match
              Suppress normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which no output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.

-l, --files-with-matches
              Suppress  normal output; instead print the name of each input file from which output would normally have been printed.  The scanning will stop on the first match.  (-l is
              specified by POSIX.)